# Выровнять меню по центру по горизонтали и убрать list style

Tags: html, css, меню

Как выровнять меню по центру по горизонтали?

**html:**

```
<div id="nav">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
         <li><a href="#education">Образование и Навыки</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">Обо мне</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Связаться</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#nav ul li a {
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:47px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#000;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**так выглядит при тесте:**

[image: так выглядит при тесте]

Comment: Немного отредактировал ответ, надеюсь что смысл сохранил.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```css
#nav{
    background: #345;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    color:#FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #345;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
         <li><a href="#education">Образование и Навыки</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">Обо мне</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Связаться</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, почти то что нужно) как сделать фон на всю ширину, а не только на кнопки?

Comment: @Valeryyy обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

```css
#nav{
  display: block;
  position: relative; 
}

#nav ul{
  width:300px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}

 
#nav ul li a {
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
#nav ul li{
  list-style-type: none
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
         <li><a href="#education">Образование и Навыки</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">Обо мне</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Связаться</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

[вот](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvZjYj)